# Reboot without filesystem access and root over SSH

Tags: linux

Micro SD died middle of a pacman update. How do I reboot it remotely (have a SSH session active)? I think that might solve the problem.

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 running Arch Linux ARM aarch64.

Anything involving `sudo` won't work because:

> /usr/bin/sudo: Input/output error

Comment: Try the reboot command but I think you're hosed without sudo.

Comment: If `sudo` isn't working in this manner then there's little chance that anything else will work either.

Comment: There's sysrq reboot, but that requires root: https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/rebooting-magic-way

Comment: If the SD is hosed, the chance it boots well are slim.

Comment: Remove power, replace SD card, attach power.